# How to merge features while keeping the originals

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector, merge

I have a polygon layer of basins and want to merge some of the basins, but still keep the sub-basins that form the larger basin. Is that possible without first duplicating the sub-basins?

Comment: Are your basins in a database?

Comment: the basins are in a shp file (vectorized from r.watershed)

Comment: I wonder what should happen for the attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0. Start layer editing.
1. Select features with the mouse.
2. Copy features with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>C</kbd>.
3. Paste copied features with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>V</kbd>.
4. Use `Merge Selected Features` button located on the editing panel.
5. Save and stop layer editing.

Сlick to watch the video below in a new tab:

[image]

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I'm trying to do.
But when I merge, the original features are deleted.

Comment: @H.Wiener Answer updated.

Comment: It does not fulfill the requirement "Is that possible without first duplicating the sub-basins?" because of the short living copy of the basins to be merged but I guess OP has a practical aim and that does not really matter.

Comment: It's a bit of a nag and I was hoping there's a faster solution that I was not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the ones you want to merge
2. Dissolve selected features
3. Multipart to singlepart on the dissolved
4. Merge (the geoprocessing merge vector layers tool) the output with your original data set

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the part "without first duplicating the sub-basins" for some reason needs to be taken seriously (not duplicating a single one of the sub-basins) then I do not know how to do it with QGIS. Or maybe the solution by BERA does it.

This way it can be done with ogrinfo.

Source data with 3 features

```
ogrinfo mergetest.shp -al

Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 3
OGRFeature(mergetest):0
  class (String) = A
  POLYGON ((200 360,340 380,360 260,240 260,200 360))

OGRFeature(mergetest):1
  class (String) = A
  POLYGON ((340 380,460 400,480 220,360 260,340 380))

OGRFeature(mergetest):2
  class (String) = B
  POLYGON ((240 260,360 260,360 160,280 160,240 260))
```

Union the polygons which belong to class A and add the result into the shapefile:

```
ogrinfo -dialect SQLite -sql "insert into mergetest (geometry) select ST_Union(geometry) from mergetest where class='A'" mergetest.shp
```

Check the result

```
ogrinfo mergetest.shp -al

Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 4

OGRFeature(mergetest):0
  class (String) = A
  POLYGON ((200 360,340 380,360 260,240 260,200 360))

OGRFeature(mergetest):1
  class (String) = A
  POLYGON ((340 380,460 400,480 220,360 260,340 380))

OGRFeature(mergetest):2
  class (String) = B
  POLYGON ((240 260,360 260,360 160,280 160,240 260))

OGRFeature(mergetest):3
  class (String) = (null)
  POLYGON ((460 400,480 220,360 260,240 260,200 360,340 380,460 400))
```